# Add custom background color in wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add custom background color in each Wordpress post so that in each post show different background color my own choice. for example: First post BG Color = Red color, Second post BG Color = Blue Color, Third post BG Color = Green color...and so on.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieved what I wanted, I added post types (Standard, Audio, Video, Aside, Gallery...etc) for different posts and then I changed the post type template (content-audio.php,content-aside.php,.. etc) from theme editor and added a container div with a unique class name. Then I created those class in style.css with background color attributes.